# openssl SSL_accept error

Tags: openssl

I need to give users the ability to switch between SSL  and non-SSL communications.  To do this, the SSL code looks for a specific command packet, shuts down the SSL stuff and starts normal TCP/IP communications.  This works fine. However, when I try to restart everything to run in SSL mode, I get a -2 error from SSL_accept.  There must be something I am not cleaning up but I haven't found it after a lot of searching for cleanup suggestions, all of which I've thrown in as shown below:

```
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
BIO_free(acc);
CONF_modules_unload(1);
OBJ_cleanup();
EVP_cleanup();
ENGINE_cleanup();
CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
ERR_remove_state(0);
ERR_free_strings();
```

Hard to believe anything is left to clean up after that!

Answer (score 0):

You should post more code to know exactly how you are receiving the error. If you make an `SSL_get_error` of the SSL_accept that fails, what exactly you receive?

Appart from those recommendations, I can see that you are doing a `BIO_free`, sometimes deppending of the underlying `BIO_METHOD` it could close the connection, and I assume you are reusing it for the next SSL_accept, wich may be the problem:

> Calling BIO_free() may also have some effect on the underlying I/O structure, for example it may close the file being referred to under certain circumstances. For more details see the individual BIO_METHOD descriptions.

From BIO_free [man](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_new.html).

If you want to reuse the connection you should check `BIO_pop` [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_accept.html).